# rsync inconsistancies

Tags: linux, mac-osx, rsync

It appears that not all files are copying over when using rsync to copy files from a mac to a FAT formatted external drive.

I'm copying over 45 files and the 43 file looks like it's missing and there's a cached version of the missing file.  However, when I hook up the external drive to a linux machine or a windows machine all of the files are present and none are missing. I wonder if this is just an issue with OSx 10.5 and if there's another alternative to copying the files on the external drive via the command line? I know there's cp but is at good as rsync?
command: `rsync -ruvWP`

Comment: Give an example of the file/path names that are not copying. What do you mean by a "cached version"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're `rsync`ing to an external drive and expecting to see every file in the source directory listed in `rsync`'s output, but some of the files aren't showing up.

`rsync` **sync**hronizes data between two locations -- If the contents already match it doesn't waste time copying it again.
If it's not copied `rsync` doesn't output it in the list of files it sent/received.

It sounds like `rsync` is working as designed -- see [the rsync manpage](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) and the associated links for more info..

Comment: Hi, That's correct. Rsync is writing all files to the drive. I can see all the files when the drive is mounted on my linux machine or when it's mounted on my windows machine. However when I mount the drive on my Mac machine, it shows that a file is missing And there's also a weird file with a Tilda in the name.

Comment: I'm only seeing this issue on Mac 10.6 using rsync. For now I'm going to use cp or python's shutil?